# How to put customize html mail in default opencart mail?

Tags: javascript, html, css, opencart, e-commerce

I want to put customize html mail in opencart !
Like when a order is received , a default message is sent through opencart but these mail very boring, I want to put HTML mail which is now used by all e-commerce website.

Can anyone tell me how can I do it, which file to edit??
where to put html and css file?

Answer (score 0):

Edit this file:

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/mail/order.tpl
```